# Subtract a number from list in the order

Tags: jquery, subtraction

I have a number as variable in jQuery, and I have list from numbers as following in html

- 100$
- 130$
- 140$
- 320$

This list of installment values for 4 months

Now I want to subtract the number from this list in the order

**For example:** the number is `130$`, it must do the list as the following list

- 0$
- 100$
- 140$
- 320$

It has removed the first month value and remaining mean (30$) from secondary months

How can I do it in jQuery?

HTML markup:

```
<ul> 
   <li><span id="month-1">100$</span></li> 
   <li><span id="month-2">130$</span></li> 
   <li><span id="month-3">140$</span></li> 
   <li><span id="month-4">320$</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please put the HTML code

Comment: <ul>
 <li><span id="month-1">100$</span></li>
 <li><span id="month-2">130$</span></li>
 <li><span id="month-3">140$</span></li>
 <li><span id="month-4">320$</span></li>
</ul>

Comment: Ok, now please try to formulate the question in proper english so that I understand what you need exactly

Comment: Need to put more effort into explaining issue more clearly and format code with proper indents for readability. [ask]

Comment: @Sabbin he wants to take each li item html as a integer, subtract the variable from the first item in list. If the first becomes less then zero put zero and the remaining is removed from the second and so on

Comment: @LelioFaieta ok, that's more clear...

Comment: thenk  Lelio Faieta :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 100; //how much you want to substract

$.each($('ul li span'), function(i,v){
  var val = $(v).html();
  val = parseInt(val.replace('$',''));
  if(val < value){
    value = value - val;
    val = 0;        
  }
  else{
    val = val - value;
    value = 0;
  }
  $(v).html((val+'$'));      
});
```

Try this

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ts3ae3f/4/)**

Comment: please helpme it must do it